# How can I annotate a django-mptt TreeQuerySet from aggregate values of children?

Tags: python, django, django-mptt

Suppose I have the following django-mptt tree:

- Root node

  - Node 1
  - Node 2
  - Node 3

    - Node 3.1
    - Node 3.2
      ...

Every node has the same fields with numerical values (e.g. area, value etc).
Can I use a TreeQuerySet to aggregate values (Sum, Count, Avg etc.) of a node with values from its children and its own values? Or should I look into annotating instead of aggregating?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

```
Node.get_descendants(include_self=True).aggregate(Sum('value'))
```

Comment: That requires some iteration over the TreeQuerySet and a calculation for each node. The iteration should start at the "lowest" tree nodes (the highest level value) and move "upwards" (higher level values) to propagate values from the children to the parent. Could be slow for a lot of nodes though.